# Redirect rewrite rule, Adding parameter at the end of url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

If /c/ is part of URL parameter then I want to add parameter at the end of URL parameter. because parameter may increase or decrease.

```
    http://example.com/c/file.php?par1=val1&par2=val2
```

I need add two parameter `&addpar1=val&addpar2=val` at the end of URL like this.

```
    http://example.com/c/file.php?par1=val1&par2=val2&addpar1=val&addpar2=val
```

What I am trying to do here:

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c/(.*)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule /c/ /%1 [QSA]
```

Please suggest me what should written in `RewriteRule` here.

Answer (score 3):

Your rule is close, but you're not actually adding anything to the query string. Try:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING !&addpar1=val&addpar2=val
 RewriteRule ^/?c/(.*)$ /%1?%{QUERY_STRING}&&addpar1=val&addpar2=val [L]
```

Here, you need to check that the parameters has already been added, then you add them to the end of the query string. You don't want the `QSA` flag here because you're manually doing the appending.

If you want to redirect the browser so that they see the query strings then you need an `R` or `R=301` flag in the square brackets (separated by a comma).